# SignalR Hub: Unhandled exception

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub

I've found the following error on the event viewer of my SignalR Server and I can't understand what could possibly cause that. Any tip?

```
An unhandled exception occurred and the process was terminated.

Exception: System.NullReferenceException

Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

StackTrace:    at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.Transports.ServerSentEventsTransport.OnStartFailed()
   at System.Action.Invoke()
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.Infrastructure.TransportInitializationHandler.<>c__DisplayClasse.<CompleteFail>b__d()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
```

Comment: What version of SignalR? .NET version ?

Comment: SignalR 2.2.0 @MichalLevý

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug. More details [here](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/3376). Currently assigned to be fixed in 2.2.1.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by stack trace and [the code](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/2.2.0/src/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client/Transports/ServerSentEventsTransport.cs) in `OnStartFailed()` method I guess its some threading issue\race condition inside SignalR. Best you can do is probably report it at SignalR Github...